# How to "do not stretch axis in matplotlib "

Tags: python, matplotlib, fft

I'm plotting many FFT's into a surface plot with Axes3D.plot_surface and got this plot out of it 
[image]
My problem is that the y-axis (Time in FFT) is stretched for the whole space of the figure. 
I just want to reduce the lines to the number of FFT's. That means that the space between FFT1 and FFT2 etc. shouldn't be colored and/or shorter. Like the desired plot:
[image: desired plot]
So my question is, how to make the Y-Axis shorter than now. 
OR, how to stop the interpolation between the FFT's

fft_count is the amount of FFT's that will be used in the plot.
I already tried:

1. `plt.tight_layout()`: Does nothing
2. `ax.set_ylim(1,fft_count)`: Just plots the values between 1-End. Its nice but no solution
3. `ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(linearLocator(fft_count)`: Just shows the ticks of the FFT's. Good but no solution
4. `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(X,Y))`: Just changes the initialize figsize. Because of the rotation
         possibilities no solution

And I tried a few more settings but I did not find the right one.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is something unclear ? So i'll try to concretize it.

Comment: Those are many questions in one. Seems that part of it that you plot a surface plot, but are rather looking for a [set of polygons](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/polys3d.html). Concerning spacing, if `figsize` is not considered a valid solution, you will need to change the aspect, which is possible but requires some tweaking. (There are smth like 10 or more questions on that, some have better answers than others)